# SaveAllAction.class is missing org.eclipse.ui.workbench Plugin for eclipse 4.7.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

SaveAllAction.class is missing in this org.eclipse.ui.workbench Plugin. I found one [doc](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blame/master/releng/planning/mars/search_o_other.csv#L278), but I didn't understand, what they are used as the alternate.

Comment: Check out https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveAllAction` was an **internal** class which you should not have been using. It was removed long ago in one of the Eclipse 3 releases.

The current equivalent is the `org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll` command. You can execute this command using something like:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IHandlerServicer handler = window.getService(IHandlerService.class);

handler.executeCommand("org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll", null);
```

Comment: org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll command didn't find in the Eclipse 4.7.2. saveAllAction = new SaveAllAction(             PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() );  Please tell me where we can find it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll` is a **command** declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands' extenion point. See example in answer.

Comment: When I tried your suggestion , IHandlerServicer is depricated.    public static Action getSaveAllAction()
   {
      if (saveAllAction == null)
      {
         saveAllAction = new SaveAllAction(
               PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() );
      }

      return saveAllAction;
   }       This is my method, where I want to use and save multiple editors.

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.IHandlerService` is not deprecated. It is used all over the place in Eclipse. Check you are importing the correct things.

Comment: But i am using this   public static Action getSaveAllAction() { if (saveAllAction == null) { saveAllAction = new SaveAllAction( PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() ); } return saveAllAction; }    here we need return as action.

Comment: If you want an action you will have to write it yourself as the old one no longer exists.